# How to extract regex group through Redshift psql

Tags: regex, amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift, psql

The same regex pattern I tried on python and Redshift psql, works on python but not on Redshift psql.

I have the strings look like this:
`s = 'AB.w127 xyz (9f6h, 89) amf, like mr .345x980 abcd'`
**I want to extract everything between "AB" and ".345x980"** ("w127 xyz (9f6h, 89) amf, like mr " in this case), the multiplied numbers here will vary, and the content in between is totally unpredictable.
So in my Redshift psql query, I used `regexp_substr(s, 'AB\.(.*?)\.\d+x\d+.*?')`. I was hoping to at least get something so that later I can use `group(1)` as python logic.

But Redshift kept showing me this error:

> Invalid preceding regular expression prior to repetition operator.  The error occured while parsing the regular expression: 'AB.(.*?>>>HERE>>>).d+xd+.*?'.

I also tried the pattern `AB\\.(.*?)\\.\\d+x\\d+.*?')`, but still got the same error.

Is there anyway to extract the string with Redshift psql?

Comment: Maybe try this pattern?  `'^AB\\.(.*)\\.\\d+x\\d+.*$'`

Comment: Can you please edit the question and supply some more examples of inputs and desired output, so we can test a regex expression for you?

Comment: Please post a more complete test sample if the greedy version does no good.

Comment: Edited. I want to extract "w127 xyz (9f6h, 89) amf, like mr " in this case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately, Amazon Redshift features only [POSIX regex](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/pattern-matching-conditions-posix.html) that does not support lazy quantifiers.

That said, it looks like you do not need them, `AB\.(.*)\.\d+x\d+` should do.

---

Regarding your question how to extract the text in-between we have very little options with regex feature of Redshift. <strike>All</strike> Most of the good stuff is unsupported. It's probably best to extract first and then use `CHARINDEX` and `SUBSTRING` to isolate the inner part.

However, one final trick is using

```
regexp_replace( text, '.*AB\.|\.\\d+x\\d+.*')
```

As stated in the linked documentation, POSIX-style \d character classes have to be using two backslashes (`\\`) or use the equivalent character class expression, e.g. `[[:digit:]]`

Comment: One final trick might be using `regexp_replace( text, '.*AB\.|\.\d+x\d+.*')`

Comment: The `regex_replace()` did give me a pretty good inspiration! I just made a little change and the problem solved, by using `regexp_replace(s, 'AB\.|\.\\d+x\\d+.*')`

Answer (score 0):

Really appreciate the answers! Finally the problem solved with `regexp_replace(s, 'AB\.|\.\\d+x\\d+.*')`, here I had to use `\\d`, otherwise Redshift gave me empty result